# Can you refer to constructor function's property inside constructor's arguments?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a simplified constructor function:

```
const Brick = function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.width = 60;
    this.height = 10;
}
```

Is it possible to refer to the properties of this constructor function during instantiation?
All of the following don't seem to work.

```
const brick1 = new Brick(Brick.width, 200);
const brick1 = new Brick(this.width, 200);
const brick1 = new Brick(brick1.width, 200);
```

This example is very trivial so it doesn't really matter that I can't refer to the width of the brick when I'm making a new instance, but in my more complex program, it would be really useful if I could. Is there a clean and simple way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the static values on the prototype, you could refer to the prototype:

```
const Brick = function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
}
Brick.prototype.width = 60;
Brick.prototype.height = 10;
```

```
const brick1 = new Brick(Brick.prototype.width, 200);
// brick1 will have:
// xpos: 60, ypos: 200, width: 60, height: 10
```

You could also use default values on an object argument instead, if you want to default to the width or height:

```
const Brick = function({ xPos = 60, yPos = 10 }) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.width = 60;
    this.height = 10;
}
```

```
const brick1 = new Brick({ yPos: 200 });
// brick1 will have:
// xpos: 60, ypos: 200, width: 60, height: 10
```